# How can I automatically fit elements in libGDX layouts?

Tags: java, libgdx

Recently I wanted to use libGDX's `Table` to show four buttons. But my table doesn't fit on the stage:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
table.add(new GameButton("1"));
table.add(new GameButton("2"));
table.add(new GameButton("3"));
table.add(new GameButton("4"));
table.align(Align.bottom);
table.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(table);
```

(`GameButton` is a `TextButton` subclass with a special `TextButtonStyle`.)

When I change `table.add(new GameButton("1"));` to `table.add(new GameButton("1")).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4);`

I get this result:
[image]

Does `Table` (or another libGDX layout class) have functionality to auto-fit elements like in the second picture? Or I should always add some width/height options after adding element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

As Josh Petrie said, we should use `.expand().fillX()` after adding each button. After that we should override `getMinWidth()` method for GameButton class (for example, with `return 0`). As result, you get correct layout!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out the `fillX()` (and `fillY()`) methods on the table, documented [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#fill).

The fill methods cause a widget to be sized to the cell subject to the minimum and maximum [size constraints of the widget itself](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#widget-size). You'd probably want to do something like `table.add(new GameButton("1")).expand().bottom().fillX();`

Comment: I tried your version and here's result: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lqV5Z.jpg). As you can see, right button is bigger than other, and all buttons overlap each other. So it doesn't look nice.

Comment: I'd guess that has to do with your minimum size constraints on the button type (or with the expand call, which you may not need depending on the other style properties set).